# multiple connection management

Tags: windows, networking, internet

In Windows O.S. I am connected with both wired and wireless connection. I would like to connect application A with wireless and application B with the wired connection. Is there any application that does this?

Maybe worth to mention that I want to dedicate one connection to VPN but it is not important for now.

I don't have any condition -> Free or paid, opensource or not opensource.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/114109/how-to-set-up-application-specific-routing-table-on-windows